# Convert Discrete Riccati Equation to LMI for multi-model LQG problem

Tags: linear-matrix-inequality

I am interested in solving the multi-model discrete-time LQG problem, that is to synthesize a stabilizing output feedback controller that stabilizes all systems with matrices $A_i, B_i,C_i,D_i$ with $i=1, ...,n$ . The problem for the single model case requires solving two discrete Riccati equations of the form:

$A_x^TXA_x-X-A_x^TXB_x(I+B_x^TXB_x)^{-1}B_x^TXA_x+Q_x = 0$
and
$A_y^TYA_y-Y-A_y^TYC_y(I+C_y^TYC_y)^{-1}C_y^TYA_y+Q_y = 0$.

(more information about how these 2 Riccati equations lead to a solution for the single model discrete-time LQG problem at Zhou, K., Doyle, J. C., & Glover, K. (1996). Robust and optimal control (Vol. 40, p. 146). New Jersey: Prentice hall. Paragraph 21.5)

Is there a way to convert both discrete Riccati equations to two LMIs, so that we can stabilize all $i$ models, by performing an optimization constrained by $2*i$ LMI's?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: When solving a LMI I believe it returns any solution as soon as it finds one, so this might not be optimal in the same sense as LQG is. Maybe one could instead formulate it as an optimization problem in the state feedback and observer gain.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it is this formulation I am looking for.